# iOS GoogleMaps SDK crashes when removing polylines

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm having this problem with GoogleMaps SDK for iOS v1.2 where the code crashes when I remove polylines.

In redrawPolylines I strip all polylines from a map and update with a new set. The section runs just fine but when GoogleMaps gets to the stage of redrawing the map it  crashes somewhere within Google's own code

Leave out the bit where I remove the old polylines and no crashing

```
-(void) redrawPolylines
{

    for (GMSPolyline* polyline in self.mapView.polylines) {
        polyline.map=nil;
    }

    [self drawPolylines];
}
```

Anyone come up against this?

Comment: Can you provide us with the stack trace?

Comment: Are you removing the polylines in a background thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google swiftly released 1.2.1 yesterday which fixes a crash with poly lines. I would try that first.

Comment: Actually 1.2.2 just got released!